# SQL Server execute SP within SP and use results of internal SP call

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to execute a stored procedure within another stored procedure and take results of the internal stored procedure to use in the external stored procedure.

Simply like follows.

**SP1**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spExternal
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @intInternalResult INT

    SET intInternalResult= EXEC spInternal
END
```

**SP Internal**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInternal 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 1+2
END
```

Comment: What is the problem then you have? You can call any scalar or table function or procedure in your first procedure and handle the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Friend,
You can not assign value to a variable which you are not returning. You can write a function to do job of stored procedure spInternal which will return a value. Else you can do it this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInternal 
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 1+2
END

CREATE PROCEDURE spExternal
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @intInternalResult INT
    CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
        Rslt int
    )
    INSERT INTO #temp (Rslt)
    EXEC spInternal

    SELECT @intInternalResult = Rslt
    FROM #temp
    DROP TABLE #temp
    PRINT @intInternalResult
END

EXEC spExternal
```

And one more thing, next time don't forget to put @ in front of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure is only returning a single integer value, use `RETURN`

```
create proc pInternal
as
begin
    return 2
end
```

then you can access the result as

```
exec @intInternalResult = pInternal
```

If you are returning non integer or multiple values, use `OUTPUT` parameters

Comment: Return codes are generally used to [indicate execution status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778(v=sql.105).aspx) i.e. success/failure; OUTPUT parameters are usually preferred for returning scalar values.